# By adding same item to recyclerview in shopping cart its overriding

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How to update a recyclerview item it its already exists, in shoping cart system? when i add an item 2 times then if i delete one then the second one will appear ,only after deleting the first one in android studio using java

```
... CartModel cart = new CartModel(namee, manufacture, avail_cart, e__pnum, m__pnum, String.valueOf(p), quantityy, String.valueOf(roundoff));
                        if (db.addToCart(cart)) {
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product added to cart  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //roundoff
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Product added to cart ",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product not added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Product not added to cart ",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

...

```
public boolean addToCart(CartModel cartModel) {


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Manufacturer, cartModel.getManufacturer());
    values.put(Availability, cartModel.getAvailability());
    values.put(E_part, cartModel.getE_part());
    values.put(M_part, cartModel.getM_part());
    values.put(Unit_price, cartModel.getUnit_());
    values.put(Quantity, cartModel.getQuantity());
    values.put(Line_total, cartModel.getLine_total());
    values.put(Name, cartModel.getName());
    return db.insert(CartDetails, null, values) > 0;


}
```

Comment: explain more , add pictures of phenomenon if possible

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan by clicking add to cart again on a product , it added to cart but not updated, its like in behind ,when i remove the first time added item the 2nd time added item in recyclerview appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to query the database if `cartModel.getName()` already exists. If yes, use [db.update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#updateWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) else use `db.insert`.

Comment: but how will it insert for the first time ,if i use update

Comment: thanks i am trying that, but what about the item position, because i am adding from product description activity

Comment: thanks ,it worked by searching and deleting that item and then added it